# Line break not displaying in report

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, report, ms-access-2013

I created an Access 2013 report using a linked table from Sharepoint.  In Sharepoint, the field is defined as "Multiple lines of text, Plain Text", in Access it comes down as "Long Text".

The field contents contains line breaks.  In Access the field is "Can Grow=Yes" and "Text Format=Plain Text".

The problem is the report displays the field without the line breaks.  Any ideas?

In Access I verified there are chr(10) characters but no chr(13) characters in the field.  I tried replacing the chr(10) with chr(10) & chr(13) but that didn't work.  It just seems to be ignoring the chr(10) character in the printed output.

Comment: The replacement failed because should be `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` - that order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a work around which is to use the 'Rich Text' report field property on the 'Plain Text' field:

1. Replace `chr(10)` with `<br/>` in the field on the report i.e.

   ```
   =Replace([fieldname],Chr(10),"<br/>")
   ```
2. Change the text box 'Text Format' property from 'Plain Text' to 'Rich Text'

Comment: Rich Text and HTML tag are not necessary. `Replace([fieldname], Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))` - Chr(13) must precede Chr(10).

Comment: @June7 your solution makes sence, but for some reason does not work right. In reports it only works for the first "instance" of the textbox. While the accepted answer works in all cases.

Comment: Perhaps has something to do with Sharepoint because it does work for me. I have never used Sharepoint.