# Line breaks access user form and reports

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, textbox, line-breaks

I'm building a database on MS Access. I have 2 text box control which are both set as long text and see formatted as plain text. When the user enters data into these fields, most of the time it's a couple of paragraphs of text, so line breaks are required to start a new paragraph. I have both fields set to go to new line after hitting the enter button. Up until I linked the data tables to SharePoint the textbox fields on the userforms and reports would show those line breaks between paragraphs just fine. Now that I have linked the database tables to SharePoint, those line breaks don't show and it's now just a text box of run on plain text. Not showing the necessary breaks between paragraphs. I checked the SharePoint table, and the field in the table shows the breaks perfectly. I then checked the field in the data table within the database and it appears those breaks aren't there. And thus those breaks won't show in the userforms when the record is called up to view in a userform and even reports.

Any advise to possibly fix this would be a big help!!! I'm at the tail end of this project and not having theses breaks between paragraphs makes things look messy.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break not displaying in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864130/line-break-not-displaying-in-report)

Comment: Maybe. In step one of the post the person is suggesting to use code. Where in the field an I putting this code? I'm willing to try it. Just not sure where that code is supposed to go

Comment: It is expression used in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: However, I took another look at that link and realized it is probably not necessary to use Rich Text. It should work but so should this: `Replace([fieldname], Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))`. That expression can be done in query or textbox.

Comment: Ok. I guess what I dont understand is that my control source for the textbox is already linked to the data table so I can store the data and pull it up in the userforms. So am I creating a different textbox with the expression called out in the post pointed me to?

Comment: Sorry. Just realized you wrote another post. I think I see what your saying. I'll try to add another column to my query that runs this data between the form and table and place this expression in the new column of the query and see what happens. I'll post an update as soon as possible

Comment: Instead of binding textbox to field, put expression in ControlSource or calculate in query and bind textbox to calculated field.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. It worked. I've only done this for the report so far. Still have to do it for the userform textbox controls. Non the less I'll mark this as solved soon as I can find where the check mark is on this post lol. Thank you for your time helping me work through this.

Comment: Can't mark as 'solved' because there is no answer response, only comments. Can upvote comments to emphasize their contribution.